# Where should I place a stove master switch on an island?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, design

We're having our kitchen redone and I would like to integrate our free-standing stove into the island unit.

Where would be decent place to put the stove master switch within this island as there are no walls available directly nearby?

Comment: A picture of the island plans might help in suggesting possible switch locations.

Comment: We don't have master switches for stoves in the US. Could you explain how this works?

Comment: Interesting. Yeah, we don't have master switches in many other parts of the world. Could someone comment on the legal/building code, reasons, and requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to place the switch in a convenient accessible location, where it will be out of the way but still usable.  Without some type of plans/drawings/pictures of the island, the answer will have to be fairly generic.

**Do Not:**

- **Do Not** place the switch where liquid is likely to be spilled on it.
- **Do Not** place the switch where children can easily access it.
- **Do Not** place the switch where it could be mistakenly toggled.
- **Do Not** place the switch inside a cabinet or drawer.
- **Do Not** place the switch where you will have to lean over (a presumably) hot stove.
- **Do Not** place the switch where it could easily be confused with a light switch.

**Do**

- **Do** place the switch where it can easily be reached.
- **Do** place the switch near the stove (within arms reach preferably).
- **Do** place the switch in an obvious easily visible location.
- **Do** use a protective cover plate to protect against accidental toggle (by yourself/children/pets) *Not a locking cover, you want to be able to access it in case of emergency*.

Comment: I'm curious as to what your reasoning is for not putting it inside a cabinet?

Comment: @Conor Boyd: The switch could accidentally be toggled while putting things in, or taking them out of the cabinet.  A switch in the cabinet is not easily found, and it may not be obvious what the switch controls.  It's also less useful in an emergency if the switch is hidden away.

Comment: Basically, the switch should be easy to reach (**and find**) if a frying pan catches on fire, along with a fire blanket that is easy to reach and find.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go the other way from Tester101 and suggest you DO put it inside one of the cabinets in the island.  That's what we've done in our house in New Zealand.